# Asymptotic analysis with combination $\frac{{n \choose k}2^k}{{2n \choose k}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, asymptotics, combinations

Consider the following inequality:

$$\frac{{n \choose k}2^k}{{2n \choose k}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$

I would like to know how fast does the largest $k$ grow as $n$ grows, in order words, i want to find the function $f$ where:
$$k = O(f(n))$$

---

What I did was I wrote a python programs and for each $n$ I iterate through $k$ and this is what I got:
[image]

It seems like $k = O(\sqrt{n})$, but I'm not sure how to confirm it, I have a limited math background and I'm not even sure what branch of mathematics I should look into :).

EDIT: Please don’t be too generous to give me a full solution, I would love to work it out myself with the right tools in hand :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for the largest $k$ such the inequality holds for some given $n$?  Have you looked at [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is related to the birthday paradox

Comment: The *smallest* such $k$ is $0$

Comment: @saulspatz my apology, you were right, I was indeed looking for the largest $k$, I have fixed my question accordingly.

Comment: @saulspatz And I missed the Stirling's formula part, I will read it up, thanks!

Comment: I've been playing with Stirling's formula, but I haven't gotten anywhere.  There's some things in [this paper](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/shagnik/notes/binomials.pdf) that might help, though.

Comment: @saulspatz I checked it up and I recall that I did try to apply it, however I didn't get much further as well :(

Comment: @msm I do have the same feeling, however I'm not exactly sure how to apply it :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you've expressed interest in a hint, here's a pointer down one path: Let's look at the ratio of binomials here.  We have $\dfrac{2n\choose k}{n\choose k}$ $=\dfrac{\frac{(2n)!}{k!(2n-k)!}}{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}$ $=\dfrac{(2n!)(n-k!)}{n!(2n-k)!}$ $=\dfrac{(2n)\cdot(2n-1)\cdots(2n-k+1)}{n\cdot{n-1}\cdots(n-k+1)}$ $=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{2n-i}{n-i}$.  Now, distribute your $k$ factors of $2$ into the denominator here, simplify the individual terms of the product, and take logs; you should notice that you can massage this to look a lot like a Riemann sum. From there you can use Euler-Maclaurin or something similar to get an approximation to the sum and an error term, and this should be good enough for getting an asymptotic order on the appropriate $k$.